# Java GET HTTP openConnection() not encoding JSON output string properly

Tags: java, json, jsp

When I generate a string from url.openConnection()'s output stream my JSON is not properly encoded. For example, quotes in strings should have \" instead of ".

Expected:

```
recvbuff == {"question": "What is your favorite \"color\""}
```

Actual:

```
recvbuff == {"question": "What is your favorite "color""}
```

Code:

```
String recvbuff = "";
String recv = "";

URL url = new URL("http://test.com/questions");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

BufferedReader buffread = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

while ((recv = buffread.readLine()) != null) {
   recvbuff += recv;
}

buffread.close();
```

Comment: What is being sent from the server?  Can you use something like `curl` or Postman to see the "raw" data?

Answer (score 1):

try with replacing double quotes with \"

```
String result =  recvbuff .replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

or use json object api:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("message", "Hello \"World\"");
String payload = jsonObject.toString();
```